# Custom operation when accessing a smart pointer

Tags: c++

In our project, we use for some classes a special type of pointer that executes some custom code when accessing the pointee (in our case to modify the memory management for certain classes). The code looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void do_something(int i) {
    std::cout << "+++ function(" << i << ") +++" << std::endl;
}

class C {
public:
    int method() {
        std::cout << "+++ C::method() +++" << std::endl;
        return 42;
    }
};

template <class T>
class ptr : public std::unique_ptr<T> {
public:
    class proxy {
    public:
        proxy(T* t) : m_t(t) { std::cout << ">>> Begin access >>>" << std::endl; }
        ~proxy() { std::cout << "<<< End access <<<" << std::endl; }

        T* operator->() { return m_t; }

    private:
        T* m_t;
    };

public:
    ptr(T* p) : std::unique_ptr<T>(p) {}

    proxy operator->() { return proxy(std::unique_ptr<T>::get()); }
};

int main() {
    ptr<C> pc(new C);
    pc->method();
    do_something(pc->method());     // <-- problem!
    return 0;
}
```

So when using the pointer to access the underlying object, a temporary proxy object is returned, that modifies the pointer access behavior by executing code in its constructor and destructor (I suppose at the end of the line). A problem arises e.g. when combining access to the pointer with a function call like in the above example code. The program produces the following output:

```
>>> Begin access >>>
+++ C::method() +++
<<< End access <<<
>>> Begin access >>>
+++ C::method() +++
+++ function(42) +++
<<< End access <<<
```

As you can see, the temporary proxy object is only destroyed after `function()` is called. This is, however, not the desired behavior (and in our case messes with the memory management). A work-around in such cases is to save the result of the accessed method in a temporary value and separate the two calls:

```
int result = pc->method();
do_something(result);
```

This would restrict the lifetime of the proxy object to the actual access as intended. But of course this is somewhat error prone because the compiler does allow to combine both function calls, so you can easily forget it.

**Question**: Can you think of a way to either restrict the proxy objects lifetime to the actual access (I assume that is probably impossible) or to let the compiler inform you about using the construct wrongly with an error or a warning?

Comment: I'm more familiar with C programming than C++, but the `assert` command terminates the program if the condition in question is `false`. It also provides debug information as to where it terminated. You could add `assert(method(input) == expected_result);` if you are able to predict your results ahead of time... Not sure if this helped at all, good luck.

Comment: You cannot restrict the proxy lifetime to just the actual access, the rules in the language require the temporary object to be destroyed at the end of the full expression which is contrary to what you want to achieve. I am actually interested in knowing how you use this for *memory management*. There may be other approaches to your actual problem.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas The smart pointer in the real code is used to replace the memory allocator when accessing certain objects/classes. So when the object is accessed, all new memory allocations should go to a different heap, for example.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I would really not *inherit* from `unique_ptr`, but rather *compose with* it.

Next, you will have to make *some* changes to your client code: Either change the type of pointee (and replace the pointee by a wrapper); or change the type of argument from naked pointer to your work-adding pointer.

If you insist that your client function accept a naked `T *`, then any suitable conversion to this type must necessarily happen in the scope of the caller, so you can never produce your side effects "just as the pointer is dereferenced".

With that out of the way, I would personally try to go for with an approach by which a client accepts your smart pointer:

```
void do_something(WorkPointer<Foo> & p);
```

To implement `WorkPointer`, replace the dereference operator:

```
template <typename T> struct WorkPointer
{
    proxy operator->() { return proxy(m_p.get()); }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> m_p;
    // ...
};
```

You will still need the proxy if you want to do work *after* the dereference. If that's not needed, you can just put the extra work directly into the dereferencing operator.

I would argue though that the problem isn't really well defined, and that you should probably never rely on a definite time for the "after access" code call. Imagine the following use:

```
void some_function(WorkPointer<Foo> & p)
{
     Foo & f = *p;      // #1
     something_else(f);
}
```

Now both the "before" *and* the "after" code will run by the time line #1 is over. Since this is entirely typical use of pointers in general, you will have to anticipate this. However, `something_else(*p)` is an alternative invocation which would cause the "after" code to be called after the end of the function call to `something_else`.

I don't think you can get around this in any easy "drop-in replacement" way, and so you should probably redesign your code so it doesn't require this two-pronged control.

Comment: The `do_something` function in the original code does not accept any kind of pointer but rather the result of an operation executed on the object (in the example an `int`). As of the addition of `operator*`, it does not share the same behavior as `operator->` (i.e. the operator will not be reapplied until a naked pointer is found) and I don't quite see why you would need or use `operator*` there. In particular no matter what you do, the output of your program would be that of the example in the question, which is what the user wants to avoid.

Comment: But the client function doesn't work on my type ``T`` but on a return value when calling a method of ``T``. Of course, everywhere I want to use the class as an argument, I have to use my smart pointer type.

Comment: BTW, the first line is a really sound advice: prefer composition over inheritance!!! (that itself deserves the +1)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I added a whole new bit on why I think this whole thing shouldn't be done at all... (I also deleted the `operator*`, which would require a separate proxy. Indeed, the *proxy* should come with `T & operator*()` and `operator T&()` I suppose.)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I haven't really inherited from ``unique_ptr``. I was just playing around and it was the shortest implementation of my ``ptr`` class. ;)

Comment: I know this is an unusual use case for a smart pointer. I think the problem in your ``some_function()`` can be averted by not implementing ``operator*()``. This may go against usual pointer behavior but at least the compiler would show an error in that case.

Comment: @fschoenm: How do you intend on using this type of smart pointer? How do you intend on performing *memory-management* with it? Your current approach cannot be taken any further, but if you explain the actual problem there might be other solutions.